# What is the the best strategy to consume 500 Kafka topics and write Parquet?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have 500 Kafka topics. Some of them are TB level; some are MB per hour.

I want to buffer them for five minutes and write them as Parquet files to the specific location on S3. The location is changed every 5 minutes based on the topic name, time, and random id, and whenever the location changes, I send a message to the status topic. We can imagine as a transactional write operation happens every 5 minutes.

I am trying to find the best solution for my problem with Spark or Flink.

For Spark, I could use structured streaming for consuming from Kafka and write logic per topic. If I have application per topic, I will waste a lot of resources for application master(driver), if I have one application and consume all topics there, some of the topics are sparse, and the app will be highly coupled.

I am also open to suggestions other than Spark or Flink. What is my best option?

Comment: What is the send message to the status topic?

Comment: It is a message that says the write operation succeeded for that 5 minute period with the S3 location.

Comment: Right. For analytics not sure I would do, have done that.

Comment: Not sure about your master driver comment.

Comment: I was talking about spark-submit for each kafka topic. They will all reserve at least one core driver, which is 500 cores in total. This is a waste.

Comment: only need very small driver though

Comment: so you have limited transformations?

Comment: I was thinking KAFKA Connect but partitioning seems an issue and naming directories. Maybe it could work in combo with first answer provided.

Comment: Very small driver but you need to reserve it 500 times. Even though if I reserve 1 core, it will be wasting 500 cores in total for no reason.

Comment: That's why KAFKA Connect would be better and then to use a view layer for those light transformations. But you want custom locations. That I am not sure how you will achieve that. I have used KAFKA Connect and 1 topic approach otherwise, but not for 500 topics. Confluent allow one Topic and N Tpic approach as well. https://www.confluent.io/blog/put-several-event-types-kafka-topic/  I will get back.

Comment: It's a while since I looked at this aspect. But look at this https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-structured-streaming/two-topics-two-schemas-one-subscription-apache-spark-structured-streaming/read  "Filter on topic: and add batchDF.write.format(...).save(...)  // dynamic location instead of show. I am sure the N schemas can be handled more generically, but I am a little busy. Still not sure on dynamic location; there are listeners and such but not a use case for dynamic location setting, but maybe. I would need to check. In any event you can group thing, but also think of partitions.

Comment: group thing, e.g. many topics per driver plus think of partitions...

Comment: I know the topics in advance; it sounds like having one application and submitting multiple stream queries in the applicston is a better option for resource usage. I just wanted to have a clear separation for the applications, so if I change the configuration; I would only need to deploy that application.

Comment: well I would have more than 1 such app. grouping smaller sizes into 1, own such App for larger things. Bob's your uncle. A lot of work for own directory dynamically and light transform. You could of causes write a program to generate the App. Dynamic resource allocation as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented similar problem via Kafka-S3 sink where I dump files using a custom hourly S3 sink. Kafka S3 flushes files for every 500 lines to S3 which is a plain JSON and also pushes the file name to another topic "s3-file-names". 
There is a spark streamer job which consumes these file names , group name under same partition performs the JSON to parquet conversion and saves back to S3. My job currently refreshes the S3 location every minute as I have configured the S3 flush file size i.e. 500 lines accordingly.

Comment: hard to follow what you really mean.